# How to redirect stderr to a file and some echos (not stdout) to the same file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am learning bash scripting. I am trying to write a simple script that runs `apt-get update` in regular intervals using **crontab** for scheduling. I am trying to send the errors (with the time the error occurred )to a log file but I am only getting the error and not the time,

The script file ,

```
echo "----------   $(date +"%d %B %G") , $(date +%r) :";
apt-get update;
```

The crontab file (sudo crontab -e)

```
0 */5 * * * /root/scripts/update_sys.sh 2>/root/logs/updateLog 1>/dev/null
```

as far as I understood the echo statement in the script file dumps the text to the standard output, thus it ends up in `/dev/null`, but how could I include it in the log file **without the entire info** ( I mean info that `apt-get` dumps like `Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources` ) ?

Comment: You need to specify *which* output you want from `apt-get`.  You can then transform that into a filter expressed in `awk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can modify the script but not the `crontab` then the simplest is to redirect the echoes in the script to `stderr`.

```
echo "----------   $(date +"%d %B %G") , $(date +%r) :" >&2
```

All `stdout` will still go to `/dev/null` and all `stderr` will be logged along with the echoes to `stderr`.

If you can modify the `crontab` but not the script, then the simplest would be [devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235132/devnull)'s suggestion.

If you can modify either, then you have a choice.